# rt WebFallbackToRTLogin

Tags: apache, rt

I am trying to set up a somewhat basic RT install.  The non-basic parts are that I am using the Apache `mod_auth_pam` module for `auth`.  The `RT` docs talk about a config option `WebFallbackToRTLogin`.  the docs say:

> If true, allows internal logins as well as REMOTE_USER by providing a
>   login form if external authentication fails. This is useful to 
>   provide local admin access (usually as root) or self service access 
>   for people without external user accounts.

Ok, the `PAM` `auth` part is working, no problems there.  My question is about how this fallback is supposed to happen?  When I reach the RT web site I am challenged for a user and password.  The standard user/pass challenge popup only has OK & Cancel buttons.  Entering invalid credentials just gets you another popup. The `Cancel` button renders a `401 Authorization Required` page.

So, how does the `WebFallbackToRTLogin` work if I can't get to the `failure` state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that option, you need to tell Apache to allow the page to render even if authentication fails. You can usually do this with a `Satisfy any` directive. Then you should be able to access the default RT login page when the first authentication fails.